# How can I automatically login to Hotspots service?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm working on an app which logs automatically in to a hotspot service *(Fon Hotspots)*. 
The service I want to uses is a unprotected WiFi-connection which asks a login and password in the first screen you open.

I want to let the app do it automatically so you don't need to do it each time by yourself. 
*So you need to enter before your login and password in the app and save it.*

Can someone tell me which functions I need to use and how it works?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What hotspot service? Can you post the code you have for logging in to the 'service'?

Comment: I'm searching for code to login to it..

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that the iPhone takes care of network connections for you. I think you just need to test to see if the device is connected to a network and then do whatever you need to do.

Comment: I know you can do it manually but then the app does nothing. I want to give in your login and password in an app, save it and then use it as a login an password.. So everything passes automatically!